# Escaping double-quote in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json object using **JSON.parse** of an object similar to this one:

```
{"id":3,"status_id":3,"project_class":"B","project_name":"Magic i-S6/" i-F1"}
```

Where the problem stands out to be "Magic i-S6/" as the value for **project_name**

And it's returning an error like this one

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 102

I've tried using

```
str.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

But it doesn't work.

What should I do to prevent this error?

Comment: Apply `str.replace(/"/g, '\\"');` at the time the JSON is constructed, on each parameter value.

Comment: @Adder — Ick. Don't do that. Get a proper JSON serialisation library instead.

Comment: It depends how you're getting the value.  Whatever is converting the object to JSON should be doing in a standard manner in which case `JSON.parse()` should be able to correctly recreate the object.  The problem is most likely in the serialization so you should fix that.

Comment: This is proof of the general rule: don't handcraft serialised data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.replace(/"/g, '\\"');` would replace **all** the quotes in the JSON with escaped ones: Even the quotes that are needed to delimit the strings in the JSON.

You should fix this by changing the code which **generates** the broken JSON.

Trying to fix it *after* receiving it is never going to be reliable.

---

You could attempt to target the specific bit of bad data in that particular string of JSON…

```
str = str.replace('i-S6/"', 'i-S6\\"');
```

… but that isn't a robust or general solution.

Fixing the bad code which is generating the bad data is the better approach.